# Consistent errors with flow accumulation raster from Hydro1k

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, clip, flow-accumulation

I'm working with bioclim and hydro1k variables in ArcMap (10.2.2), ultimately with the goal of doing niche modeling.  I've got all my h1k variables in their original formats (Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area, 1km resolution) and I've projected all my biolcim (1km) to the same datum and spatial reference.  The only raster of all 25 that is giving me consistent problems is flow accumulation from H1k.  Previously, I could not resample to any other cell size (either got the 999998 error or an cell size too large or small error).  I've gone around that problem, but now I can't even clip the base flow accumulation raster as downloaded from H1k without getting an error.  Again, it's the 999998 "operating system" error.  I've tried disabling background processing, but it still gave me the same error.  Has anyone else experienced this sort of thing.  It seems strange that a single raster out of 25 would be acting up.  Any suggestions for how to fix this?  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: I don't know if others would agree with me but resampling a flow accumulation grid is an odd thing to do as you destroy the flow connectivity that it is representing. If this was me I would go back to the original DEM that its derived from, resample that then work the datasets up into a new flow accumulation grid.

Comment: @Hornbydd I couldn't agree with your more Hornbydd, you should never resample a flow accumulation grid directly. Rather, resample the DEM then regenerate the flow pointer/accumulation grids. Otherwise you'll likely destroy the continuous nature of flow pathways within the grid.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Right, this is why I am not resampling flow accumulation anymore.  Rather, I am bringing the H1k rasters in from the start (in their original formats and resolutions), and then projecting the bioclim in the same spatial reference as the H1k variables. The problem is that I cannot even clip the flow accumulation raster to my species distribution without an error.